# Jquery: probleme with $.ajax (json datatype)

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a problem to refresh a bloc in my page.

Here is the request:

```
> $("#pwd_lost_link").click(function(){
    alert('1');
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url: 'test.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data :{"nom" : "akbar"},
      success : function(data){
        $("#main_bloc").append(data.msg);
        alert('2');
      },
      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                                alert(errorThrown);             }
    });   })
```

and here is the php file

```
<?php  
 $return['nom'] = "ffrfrfrfr";
  echo json_encode($return)
?>
```

It doesn't work. It give me a status error ( 0 ) and the page is automatically reloaded

Thanks

Michaël

Comment: whats the page url of your html/php files?

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome's debugger to capture the HTTP response you get. Is it a 200? Does it have the correct Content-Type header?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It's test.php

Comment: Yes it's a 200. This my content type: Content-Type text/html. I think I have the solution. I have to encode the data in json format? thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusing question Michael, not sure what you mean by "the page is automatically reloaded" but you should do 2 things:

In the $.ajax() method, make sure your success called back is handling the data correctly.  You are looking for `data.msg` but I don't see where `.msg` comes from.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            // parse data object so you can see what's being returned ex. alert(data) or alert(data[0]) or alert(data.nom)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // XHR DOM reference: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp
            // check for errors  ex. alert(xhr.statusText);              
        } 
    });
```

On the PHP side, you may want to debug there to see what is being received and what you are sending back.

Aside from that using an XHR viewer like Firebug or Chrome's built-in utility (CTRL+SHIFT+I) can be very helpful.

And on a final note, if `pwd_lost_link` is a link elment `a id="pwd_lost_link" href="..."`  then you will have to stop the browser from following the link before you process the AJAX.

```
$("#pwd_lost_link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert('1');
    $.ajax({      
   ...
});
```

If you aren't seeing the '1' being alerted then that is definitely your first problem.

Comment: Thanks. It was the default :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `data.msg`, but your PHP script is only creating `data.nom`. So `data.msg` doesn't exist. Try changing `data.msg` to `data.nom` and see if this does what you want.

Comment: Thx. You're right it was an error but it doesn't resolve my problem. The "alert(2)" is never shown.